# How do I color the output of all linux commands in child-process.spawn in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, colors, command, child-process, spawn

I want to implement Linux terminal using child-process : spawn of nodejs.
All behavior is fine, but the following color output problems exist:

1. `require("child_process").spawn(mainCommand, subCommmands, {stdio: 'inherit'});`

Commands such as `npm i` and `gcc` output well in the following code, but Linux commands such as `ls -al` do not output color. Also, `stdout.on, stderr.on` via pipe option is not available because `{stdio : inherit}`.

2. so, when I add `--color=always` to the subCommands parameter and changed option `stdio: 'inherit'` to `stdio: 'pipe'`, Linux commands such as `ls -al` have good color output, but commands such as `pip, python3, gcc` have the following error with no color:
   [error: unrecognized command line option ‘--color=always’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkLOk.png)

Therefore, I would like to implement a Linux terminal that can do all of the following:

1. It shall be possible to capture output through child-process. (using stdout.on with `stdio:'pipe'`)
2. Color-preserved output should be produced for all commands (ex: `ls`, `ls -al`, `npm i`, `gcc`, `pip`, `python`, `javac` etc.).

Please let me know if you have such a child-process option or chalk option (most of the questions are asked to use chalk or supports color, but there are no specific examples of it).

My development environment is Ubuntu.

Please give me some advice, thanks.